# JavaFX - How to add ColorPicker to my scene

Tags: colors, javafx, color-picker

How can I add a `ColorPicker` to my application?
I tryed with this code:

```
public class MyColorPicker extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker();
        box.getChildren().add(cp) // Error: cp Cannot be converted to Node
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 300, 200);

        primaryStage.setTitle("colorPicker");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you have another ColorPicker-class in your classpath?

Comment: no... By the way I restarted the IDE and it works well .. :|